# Find Minum Value

Tags: number-theory, maxima-minima

I have given this equation

```
Min(a-Q,b-W,c-E,d-R) =  a-Q
```

Now i have to find the answer of the following equation

```
Min(a-K* Q, b-K* W, c-K* E, d-K* R)  and k>=0
```

From my intuition i thinks it's always **a-K*Q** , But how to prove this ?

Comment: It may depend on the signs of Q,W,E,R to get a conclusion.

Comment: @coffeemath let's assume everything is greater or equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct only for $k\geq1$. It fails when $k$ lies between $0$ and $1$.

For e.g. $a=3$, $b=1$, $Q=4$, $W=1$, $k=0.5$

Here $a-Q<b-W$ but $a-kQ>b-kW$.

Following is a proof for $k\geq1$,

$a-Q<b-W$

=> $a-b<Q-W$

=> $a-b<k(Q-W)$ for $k\geq1$

=> $a-kQ<b-kW$

Similarly for c-kE and d-kR